# I want the collapse behavior of my container block

Tags: html, css, containers

I spent hours searching the solution of this issue. All i found is the inverse of the desired behavior.
As the title says, what i want is that my '' container collapse and get no height when it have the property 'position:fixed'
This is the code block.

```
<div style="position:fixed;right:0;bottom:0">
    <div style="float:left">First DIV</div>
    <div style="float:left">Second DIV</div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: It can't have no height if it has contents...it's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Normally, the container collapse when all his contents floats (the height is null). But when the container have fixed position, it do not collapse. But the fact is that i want it to collapse.

Comment: Well,,,you can't...as far as I know, and I can't think of a reason why this would be required. Why do you need the height at 0? Perhaps an alternative solution can be found.

Comment: In fact, i want the behavior of multiple chat block grouped in the container (like on common chat clients on facebook or other sites). The container is the block fixed on bottom right the window containings one or several chat blocks.

Comment: I'm still not clear on why the **height** has to be 0. If you do this it will disappear and so will it's contents.

Comment: That is the point. I want the container to disapear (not visible) but not the contents. Exactly like collapsed DIV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i have the response of the problem. I put a middle container between the main container and the elements that have an absolute position.
The code became :

```
<div id="main_container">
  <div id="middle_container">
    <div class="element">First DIV</div>
    <div class="element">Second DIV</div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>


#main_container{
position : fixed;
right : 0;
bottom : 0;
}
#middle_container{
position : absolute;
right : 0;
bottom: 0;
}
.element{
float : left;
}
```

Thanks all for your responses. And sorry for the problem description clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments

> i want the behavior of multiple chat block grouped in the container (like on common chat clients on facebook or other sites). The container is the block fixed on bottom right the window containings one or several chat blocks.

So, in fact the height will **not** be zero but rather it seems that you want the div to have no greater height than the sum of it's contents.

If you do not specific a height on the div then this would be the default for a fixed position div.

Something like this should suffice.

```css
.mydiv {
  background: lightblue;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.mydiv div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 200px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
.mydiv div:nth-child(even) {
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
  <div>First DIV</div>
  <div>Second DIV</div>
  <div>Third loooooong DIV</div>
  <div>Fourth DIV</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam facere dolorum amet eum eos alias.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But in this case, to illustrate my problem, imagine that the container mydiv container have the property width:100%; the page will full with the lightblue background, and it is impossible to click links under it.

Comment: Unless you provide full details of the proposed requirement we can't help. Adding extra complexity as an **additional** requirement is not helpful. Obviously this div is going to sit in top of anything below it...that's what fixed positioning does.

Answer (score -1):

add height: 0px and overflow:hidden to the container div

Comment: This just hide all elements.